# Change parameter of method

Tags: java, refactoring

Say I have a following function in java, may be not good example but just came in mind ;)

```
public StudentEntity updateStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity)
{
    studentEntity.setName(...);
    studentEntity.setAddress(...);
    return studentEntity;
}
```

Is above approach valid?

Can we store a studentEntity in separate variable and update and return it.
For example

```
public StudentEntity updateStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity)
{
    StudentEntity _studentEntity = studentEntity;
    _studentEntity.setName(...);
    _studentEntity.setAddress(...);
    return _studentEntity;
}
```

Is this correct ? How mutator methods should be? Please make me correct if wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655639/bad-programming-practice-to-alter-passed-objects-in-java

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to  write

```
   StudentEntity _studentEntity = studentEntity;
```

It's just redundant.

If you are just updating and return prefer first way. The second way creates unnecessary confusion while reading the code aswell.

Comment: some thoughts on website confuses. Says do not use out parameters or do not change them. PMD or Sonar reports also says same?

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar what do you mean by that. Sorry , Did'nt get you.

Comment: His method does return the same object as it receives as a parameter. In most cases this seems redundant. An updateXY method sounds like something that mutates the given object. So no need for a return value. This pattern more reminds me of methods acting on immutable objects like Strings where the return value is a new String object.